# Google Maps API: recuperar nome do país ou cidade de uma coordenada

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Preciso checar ser uma coordenada (latitude e longitude) pertence à uma cidade ou país.

Alguém sabe uma forma simples de fazer isso utilizando o Google Maps API v3 (javascript)?

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse topico, pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268916/can-i-find-out-if-a-coordinate-is-inside-a-city

Comment: Tem em conta que se pertencer a uma cidade vai sempre pertencer a um país